# How to get a list of Stomp queues or/and topics (their names) as a client?

Tags: java, python, ruby, activemq-classic, stomp

In Stomp, how can I browse all queues or/and topics available? Is it possible at all?

The key here is to get the result and the language is not important, it can be either python, ruby or java because as I've found out it's easier to do this particular task using them because of the existing libraries. Python seems to have only one most popular library, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the simple answer is that you can't.  That's not part of the Stomp protocol.

The complex answer, as always, is "it depends". It's entirely possible that whatever is providing your stomp service will have something that you can use.  (In RabbitMQ, for example, you can log in to the web interface and look at the current queue names).

However the whole point of Stomp (and to a certain extent in all messaging) is that there aren't really "desintations", just queues which can be read by one or more clients.  And the queues are transient; you might find the information deprecates pretty quickly...

Comment: I mean, queues and topics (their names). Is it possible  to get a list of them both or one of them from a client (consumer) side?

Comment: I really don't think so, because as I said, not part of the protocol.  But maybe whatever library you are using as a client can get you something?  The Ruby 'Stomp' gem doesn't give you anything you can use...

Comment: I wonder, does a queue or topic has to be created by client (consumer) before subscribing? or should they exist already on a server before a client connects and subscribes?

Comment: Depends again, on the server implementation.  I *think* that the Stomp protocol *implies* that the client should be able to create them on the fly.  Certainly that is how it works in RabbitMQ.